# Describing a function in a list of parameters

Tags: types, erlang

I have a function description like that:

```
-spec match_evaluator(ReplaceFun, Text, Regex) -> Result
   when ReplaceFun :: function(),
        Text :: string(),
        Regex :: string(),
        Result :: string().

match_evaluator(ReplaceFun, Text, Regex) ->
```

I would like to add a more detailed description of the parameters of the parameter `ReplaceFun`. `ReplaceFun` is a link to a function.

Something like that:

```
-type replace_fun(string(),[string()]) :: {string(), non_neg_integer()}.
% : bad type variable
```

I would like to define this type correctly (a function with two parameters and return type). Please, tell me how to correctly describe the type of this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `-spec` of the function `match_evaluator`:

```
-spec match_evaluator1(ReplaceFun, Text, Regex) -> Result
   when ReplaceFun :: fun((FullString :: string(), MatchResult :: [string()]) -> 
        (NewString :: string())),
        Text :: string(),
        Regex :: string(),
        Result :: string().

match_evaluator1(ReplaceFun, Text, Regex) ->
%..
```

The idea of the solution prompted me by [@radrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4400060/radrow), [reference_manual](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html#type-information-in-record-declarations) and source code of Erlang standard library `socket_test_evaluator.erl` (which I found in the folder `erlang/otp/erts/emulator/test`).

Source code of this function is [here](https://github.com/rustkas/Regular-Expressions-Cookbook/blob/main/code/ch03/programming/lib/recipe_16/src/recipe_16.erl).

Answer (score 1):

You can write for example `fun((string(), string()) -> string())` to refer a function that takes two strings and returns a string. If you don't care what are the parameters or the return type, then use `any()` in their places. I recommend a lecture of the [Erlang documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html#types-and-their-syntax) for more options.

Comment: Thank you, Radosław for your suggestions! Unfortunately, this solution will not work. Moreover, we will get a syntax error if we add it to the `-spec` directive as is. Thanks for the link to the description of the types. The solution is implemented function description using `-type`.,  I haven't written those types yet. I am thinking about it.

Comment: Honestly speaking, I don't understand what is wrong with that notation. Could you say it in different words?

Comment: I have this description of the function:
```
-spec match_evaluator(DoAction, Text, Regex) -> Result
   when DoAction :: function(),
        Text :: string(),
  Regex :: string()|tuple(),
  Result :: string().
```

Comment: This is a general description and it fits, but I would like to detail it. [source code](https://github.com/rustkas/re_tuner/blob/main/src/re_tuner.erl)

Comment: `DoActions` is a function. Its spec is `function(string())-> string()`. I would like to add description about that.

Comment: So just write `DoActions :: fun((string()) -> string())`, doesn't that work? (note the paren)

Comment: Unfortunately no. We've got syntax error. The material contained in the article, the [link](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html#type-declarations-of-user-defined-types) to which you gave suggested to me a possible acceptable solution ( `-type orddict(Key, Val) :: [{Key, Val}].`).

Comment: `
-type do_action() :: do_action(_).

-type do_action(String) :: String.
`

Comment: I figured it out. I am confused about parentheses. @radrow 's proposed solution will work. Another way of type declaration discussed here would be: `-type do_action() :: fun((String :: string()) -> string()).` or `DoActions :: fun((InputString :: string()) -> (NewString :: string()))`

Comment: Full view (source code) of discussed solution is [here](https://github.com/rustkas/re_tuner/blob/main/src/re_tuner.erl).